# Error while trying to use tensorflow's C++ API

Tags: c++, makefile, tensorflow, bazel

I am having bit of a problem with Tensorflow. I have to integrate my code that uses TF into an already existing project (that uses Makefile). So here is what I did.

I got the TF from the source and installed it as described [on the TF site.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources)

Then I built a shared library with:

> bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so

After doing this, I add the following lines to the Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles
CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/
CFLAGS += -I/home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3

LDFLAGS += -L/home/alpy/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow
LDFLAGS += -ltensorflow
```

When I try to make it, I get this wonderful error: [link](http://pastebin.com/xHmrhZ9d)

EDIT: I forgot to explain a few stuff. I am on Linux so the compiler should be case sensitive. I checked my files and TF files and all of them seem to have #ifndef guards.

EDIT: As advised to me I am adding the error directly to the post:

```
In file included from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
[...]

  from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/public/session.h:23,
                 from ../src/conversion.h:11,
                 from ../src/detect_fast_C.cpp:43:
/home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42: error: #include nested too deeply
In file included from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1,
[...]
             from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/types.h:23,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/type_traits.h:22,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:25,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:21,
                 from /home/alpy/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/public/session.h:23,
                 from ../src/conversion.h:11,
                 from ../src/detect_fast_C.cpp:43:
/home/alpy/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42: error: #include nested too deeply
```

( This goes on for sometime)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should add all those -I includes

You can look at the reference C++ example in the bazel build system.

cc_binary.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/BUILD#L264

Flags:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L111

You can run bazel build with the `-s` option to see the actual commands issued to build the target.

Comment: When I avoid the -I includes I get errors such as:t ensorflow/core/public/session.h: No such file or directory